# How do I troubleshoot mustache blocks?

Tags: templates, templating, handlebars.js, mustache

I'm trying to use **handlebars** in my project, but am running into trouble getting it to output each object's attributes.

**Data**

```
people: [{"name":"Moe"}, {"name":"Larry"}, {"name":"Curly"}]
```

**Template**

```
{{#people}} Name: {{name}} <br/>{{/people}}
```

**Output**

```
Name: 
Name: 
Name:
```

It obviously reads the list of people, because it outputs three times. but I don't know why it's not able to see the simple path to `name`.

- If I put `{{this.name}}`, it also renders a blank.
- If I put `{{this}}`, I see `[object Object]`.

How do I log or investigate this object so I know why the *name* attribute isn't being rendered?

Answer (score 0):

try `{{#each people}} Name: {{name}} <br/>{{/each}}`

Comment: Unfortunately, I did try that with the same result. Thank you, though.

Comment: How are you passing the data into the template? For example `template(people)` won't work, but `template({people:people})` probably will

Comment: Having now looked closer at your dataset, you have a hash with 3 identical keynames, so they're just overwriting each other. I assume what you mean to do it do have a list, which would be like this:

people: [{"name":"Moe"}, {"name":"Larry"}, {"name":"Curly"}]

or, maybe ever simpler would be:

people: ["Moe","Larry","Curly"]

Comment: Thanks for catching my typo. It actually is the first example you listed. I've updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Something must be wrong with the rest of your code, in this fiddle it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/hDE3P/

```
var context = {
   people : [{"name":"Moe"}, {"name":"Larry"}, {"name":"Curly"}] 
} 
var source   = $("#entry").text();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
$("#out").html( template(context) );
```

with this html

```
<script id="entry" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#people}} Name: {{name}} <br/>{{/people}}
</script>

output:  
<div id="out"></div>
```

Try these things:

- Check your datamodel in the debugger (Firebug or sth.)
- Check your template is correct (sometimes browsers destroy it if not in script tags)
- Debug into Handlebars "each" handler to see what the context looks like

Hope this helps.